# Average of Subset of Values in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, average

I have a dataframe which has the 3 columns

```
Date    Col 2     Col 3
10/1/19    C1        0.5
10/1/19    C2        0.3
10/1/19    C3        0.2
10/1/19    C1        0.5
10/1/19    C2        0.3 
10/1/19    C3        0.2
10/2/19    C1        0.5
10/2/19    C2        0.3
10/2/19    C3        0.2
10/2/19    C1        0.5
10/2/19    C2        0.3 
10/2/19    C3        0.2
...
12/13/19   C3        0.5
```

I would like to calculate the Average of each Unique value in Col 2 for each day with the avg of Col 3.

So for example,

```
Date       Col 2       Col3 (Avg)
10/1/19       C1         0.2
10/1/19       C2         0.4
10/1/19       C3         0.3
10/2/19       C1         0.2
10/2/19       C2         0.1
...
```

I am new to python and have tried doing this in Pandas but I am not able to figure it out. Any help is appreciated. I am able to get the average of the entire column but not the subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Col 2'], as_index=False)['Col 3'].mean()

    Date   Col 2  Col 3
0  10/1/19   C1   0.5
1  10/1/19   C2   0.3
2  10/1/19   C3   0.2
3  10/2/19   C1   0.5
4  10/2/19   C2   0.3
5  10/2/19   C3   0.2
```